# Android ADB push file no read permission

Tags: android, linux, adb

I used adb shell to push a data file to android virtual device. However, this file has no user read permission. Since the device is not root, I can't use chmod to change the permission.

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw 84465664 2017-06-06 20:24 italy.sqlite
```

Since it doesn't have user permission, mu app can't open it. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It does have *group* `rw`, though, so what user account are you using?

Comment: If you run "id" cmd, you'll see you are part of sdcard_rw group.